# Binary relations on sets

Tags: combinatorics, relations

Sorry for such a query.
But can a relation be both antisymmetric as well as asymmetric?
for ex. is this relation {(3,4),(5,6)} both antisymmetric and asymmetric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, although somewhat trivially.

A relation $R$ is asymmetric iff, for any $x,y$ in the domain, $xRy\Rightarrow \neg yRx$. It is antisymmetric iff $xRy \wedge yRx \Longrightarrow y=x$. However, for an asymmetric relation $R$, the condition $xRy\wedge yRx$ is always false, which means the condition for being an antisymmetric relation is (vacuously) true.

Therefore, *every* asymmetric relation is also antisymmetric. (But not every antisymmetric relation is asymmetric.)